# How does SpaceX Raptor deliver a more benign turbine environment?

Tags: engine-design, raptor

> Raptor has been claimed to be able to deliver "long life ... and more benign turbine environments".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor

The Raptor has hot oxygen flowing out of the oxidizer preburner. This limits material choices to avoid severe oxidation. How and compared to what does that deliver a more benign turbine environment?

Comment: The full quote is from [Gwynne Shotwell testifying to Congress in 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20160128041905/http://docs.house.gov/meetings/AS/AS29/20150317/103135/HHRG-114-AS29-Wstate-ShotwellG-20150317.pdf).  See page 14.  It isn't immediately clear to me if she might be comparing it to the RD-180 or the Merlin or both.  "The engine utilizes a full flow staged combustion cycle, promising the highest performance possible for a methane rocket engine, while also delivering long life through new SpaceX technologies and more benign turbine environments."

Answer (score 3):

For the same amount of pre-turbine combustion, the gasses in a full flow turbine are *much* cooler and higher volume than those with a partial flow.
Both of these mean the tolerances in the turbo can be a little more relaxed, without losing as much performance.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?